# Stand Alone Bibliography Page

Tags: bibliographies

As part of a grant, I am asked to submit a separate pdf file of my bibliography.

How do I generate such a document on Overleaf?

I am using biblatex:

> \usepackage[ backend=biber, style=alphabetic, sorting=ynt ]{biblatex}

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "my references". Do you mean, "my publications and working papers"?

Comment: I meant bibliography.

Comment: Can you just put it at the end, restart page numbering and split the PDF?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to show the whole bibliography with the commands `\nocite`and `\printbibliography`. Once you have uploaded your .bib file on Overleaf, you can use something like this :

```
\documentclass{article}
...
\usepackage[ backend=biber, style=alphabetic, sorting=ynt ]{biblatex} % as per your question
   \bibliography{<your .bib file>}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

You can also modify the title of your bibliography by appending the following code:
`[title={<your bibliography title>}]` to `\printbibliography`.

Comment: Good suggestion, assuming everything in the `.bib` file is supposed to be included. Note by the way that `\bibliography` is considered  deprecated by `biblatex`, and that `\addbibresource` is recommended instead.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, I'll adjust my own documents accordingly ;)